# Lost at sea. What is the ship's cargo?

Tags: story, geography, cipher, history

While trapped at sea, a small fishing vessel desperately tried to reach another ship for assistance. Finally, a large ship appeared over the crest of a magnificent wave.

The crew members screamed for help, but over the noise of the storm, their voices were lost. As the other boat pulled up near the starboard to the stranded fishing craft, the captain noticed a strange insignia on their hull.

[image]

This symbol was no mystery to the captain. As an experienced and knowledgeable seaman, he knew that the symbol was the [maritime code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_maritime_signal_flags) for the letter *t*. Stranger though was its meaning when used independently: *"Keep clear of me."*

A man emerged from the hatch and shouted these words in a powerful voice that even pierced the howling winds of the storm. Even so, only snippets of his speech were remembered by the crew, and those that stood out were cryptic.

> We travel from the Island of Pelicans, where there are no pelicans.
>
> The island's second observer hails from the insignia capsized.
>
> *Do not board*

***What was the ship carrying?*** and ***Where were they?***

Comment: Is the symbol a French flag (upside down), and was the man in the hatch speaking French?

Comment: @Gamow The symbol is the maritime flag symbol for 't'. And no, the man was not speaking french

Comment: For your purposes, does "capsized" mean *fully* inverted?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you could find where they were currently or what they were carrying. However, they were coming from

> [Pigeon Island](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeon_Island_(Saint_Lucia)). François LaClerc, a pirate who used that island as a base, comes from France, which is the T flag upside-down.

Comment: I'd guess they were near that island, and they were carrying a product of the lime kilns there,

Comment: It could just be that the ship was `pbzznaqrrerq` and carrying `tbyq be gernfher be jungrire` and the man who came out of the hatch was `whfg jneavat gurz gung gurl gbb pbhyq or pncgherq`, but that seems... I dunno,  arbitrary, if it is the solution.

Comment: I recently found a mistake in the question that completely changed the premise. If you would like to change your answer to accommodate it, I will happily accept.